# How to get data like access token,refresh token from OKTA in a custom tab control?

Tags: android, tabs, controls, okta

We want to use Okta for social login, In web view we are having "shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)" or "shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) " method, in this method we are getting accesstoken,refresh token etc.
But now we want to replace webview with custom tab control, In this custom tab control we are having navigation call back, but not getting required access token,refresh token etc in bundle. also not able to identify which url is loading while redirection.
Is there any solution to get this type of data through custom tab control and to redirect to app after getting data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest taking a look at [AppAuth-Android](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-android) to handle these flows for you. By default, AppAuth uses the [Authorization Code Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749.html#section-1.3.1) with [PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) to return tokens from an IDP following best current practice documented in [OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps-12).

If you're interested - Okta wrote a wrapper around this library called [Okta AppAuth](https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-appauth-android), to make these flows easier to handle. See [their quickstart](https://developer.okta.com/quickstart/#/android/nodejs/generic) for integration instructions.